# Word by word selection by mouse in Firefox

Tags: firefox, selection

In Firefox, selection of the text by mouse occurs character by character. In MS Word selection of the text by mouse occurs word by word. This is much more usable.

Is there any plugin or setting that makes Firefox to enable word by word selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doubleclick-and-hold on the first word you want to select, then drag your selection.

Comment: I also just realised that a triple-click and drag allows you to select paragraph by paragraph! Thanks.